# ошибка в require {Replit}

Tags: javascript, html

```
const Database = require("@replit/database")
```

выводит ошибку

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Где вы пытаетесь такое использовать?

Comment: в html файле в <script></script>

Comment: У вас не получится использовать require напрямую в JS. Для этого нужен сборщик, на подобии webPack, который будет доставать из пакетов компоненты и собирать готовый JS для сайта